# How to extract a number before a certain words?

Tags: python, regex

There is a sentence "i have 5 kg apples and 6 kg pears".

I just want to extract the weight of apples.

So I use

```
sentence = "I have 5 kg apples and 6 kg pears"
number = re.findall(r'(\d+) kg apples', sentence)
print (number)
```

However, it just works for integer numbers. So what should I do if the number I want to extract is 5.5?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
import re

sentence = ["I have 5.5 kg apples and 6 kg pears",
                   "I have 5 kg apples and 6 kg pears"]
for sen in sentence:
    print re.findall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) kg apples', sen)
```

Output:

```
['5.5']
['5']
```

Comment: This matches `5.6.5` as well.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Non-regex solution

```
sentence = "I have 5.5 kg apples and 6 kg pears"
words  = sentence.split(" ")

[words[idx-1] for idx, word in enumerate(words) if word == "kg"]
# => ['5.5', '6']
```

You can then check whether these are valid floats using

```
try:
   float(element)
except ValueError:
   print "Not a float"
```

Answer (score 0):

`?` designates an optional segment of a regex.

`re.findall(r'((\d+\.)?\d+)', sentence)`

Comment: `number = re.findall(r'((\d+\.)?\d+)', sentence)` returns a list of tuples `[('5', ''), ('6', '')]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `number = re.findall(r'(\d+\.?\d*) kg apples', sentence)`

Answer (score 0):

You change your regex to match it:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

`\.\d+` matches a dot followed by at least one digit. I made it optional, because you still want one digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+.', sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need should look like this:

```
(\d+.?\d*) kg apples
```

You can do as follows:

```
number = re.findall(r'(\d+.?\d*) kg apples', sentence)
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/hHAJ3S/1) is an online example